# AVR Pin Change Interrupts fire upredicably

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, avr, atmega

So, I am using an [ATMega168](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega168.aspx) with the [NerdKits](http://www.nerdkits.com/) set and have an LCD hooked up to it, using the two interrupts INT0 & INT1.  I want to attach a [Grove Heart Rate Monitor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Chest_Strap_Heart_Rate_Sensor), which I've attached to PCINT1 and attempted to enable and use

```
void hrm_init()
{
//clear pin
  DDRB &= ~(1<<DDB0);
  PORTB |= (1<<PORTB0);
//turn on pull up
  PCICR |= (1<<PCIE0);   //enable pcint 1
  PCMSK0 |= (1<<PCINT1); //Trigger on change of PCINT1 (PB1)
  sei();
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
   uint8_t changedBits;

   changedBits = PINB ^ porthistory;
   porthistory = PINB;

   //pin has changed
   if (changedBits & (1<<PB1)) 
   {     
      beats += ((PINB & _BV(PB1)) ? 1 : 0); //add a beat on the rising edge 
   }
}
```

(The beat count code stolen from someone online, hence the use of the macro.)

This works, most of the time but can add extra beats here and there, I've seen as much as 10 while I have a timer interrupt as well (which I'll be using to calculate beats per minute).

```
void clock_init() 
{
  TCCR0A |= (1<<WGM01);
  TCCR0B |= (1<<CS02) | (1<<CS00);
  OCR0A = 143;
  TIMSK0 |= (1<<OCIE0A);
}

SIGNAL(SIG_OUTPUT_COMPARE0A) {
  the_time++;

  if (the_time > 500)
  {
    bpm = beats;
    bpm *= 12; //60 seconds divided by 5

    the_time = 0;
    beats = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that there is noise on the signal from the heart rate monitor. There are a few ways to deal with this. One is a hardware filter, but you can deal with it in software using a "de-bounce" or "de-glitch" mechanism.

Here is one "de-glitch" mechanism. You would not expect there to be two heartbeats within a few milliseconds of each other. So, you can reject (skip the count corresponding to) any rising edge within, say, two milliseconds of the previous rising edge.

If you have a free running timer with millisecond resolution, simply capture the timer at each rising edge. If the difference from the previous edge is more than 2 milliseconds, count the edge, otherwise don't count it. When you count it, save the timer value for the next comparison.

Use unsigned arithmetic to subtract and compare the result to two milliseconds. That way, you don't need to worry about timer wraparound.

```
ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
   static uint16_t last_rising_edge = 0;
   uint8_t changedBits;

   changedBits = PINB ^ porthistory;
   porthistory = PINB;

   //pin has changed
   if (changedBits & (1<<PB1)) 
   {
      uint16_t now = get_milliseconds();

      if (0 != (PINB & _BV(PB1) && (now - last_rising_edge) >= 2u)
      {
          beats += 1; //add a beat on the rising edge
          last_rising_edge = now;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I had heard about bounce but I assumed that a single line, digital signal wouldn't be subject to that, obviously I assumed wrong.  Thanks, I'll give this a go and accept if it works.

Comment: If you expect glitches on a pin which is used to trigger interrupts, you should either change the interrupt to a polling mechanism instead, or add a hardware low-pass filter. Otherwise, the input can theoretically hang up your whole CPU, so that it does nothing else but executing interrupts. This is particularly true for sluggish 8-bit MCUs.

Comment: I initially tried polling about 10 times per second but it seemed to be receiving strange results, multiple on or off beats in a row then large breaks between beats (this compared to a functioning hrm watch). Interrupts seemed to work much better.  As my heart can't beat more than 4 times per second and as long as I keep the code in my interrupt routine short, should this still be a problem?
Also, would a low-pass filter be a better bounce eliminator than software?

Comment: The pulses from the heart rate monitor look quite short if the scope trace on their web page is at all accurate; I'd estimate the duty cycle at less than 1%. So, polling will not work. I believe the solution I presented in the answer above is the best software approach. It will also work with a hardware filter.